# Returning a recursive iterator from a function

Tags: rust

I have a function that [returns a flat-mapped `Vec` over children of a tree](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b006dd1977f4bea0672501ae4426fd32):

```
use std::iter;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Tree {
    value: String,
    children: Vec<Tree>,
}

struct NoClone;

impl NoClone {
    pub fn children(&self, from: &Tree) -> Vec<Tree> {
        from.children.clone()
    }

    pub fn descendants_vec<'a>(&'a self, from: Tree) -> Vec<Tree> {
        let children = self.children(&from);
        iter::once(from)
            .chain(children.into_iter().flat_map(|child| self.descendants_vec(child)))
            .collect::<Vec<Tree>>()
    }

    pub fn descendants_iter<'a>(&'a self, from: Tree) -> Box<Iterator<Item = Tree> + 'a> {
        let children = self.children(&from);
        Box::new(iter::once(from)
                     .chain(children.into_iter().flat_map(move |child| {
                                                              self.descendants_iter(child)
                                                          })))
    }
}

fn main() {
    //println!("Flattened (Iter): {:?}", mapped_iter());
    println!("Flattened (Vec): {:?}", mapped_vec());
}

fn tree() -> Tree {
    let tree_a = Tree {
        value: "a".to_owned(),
        children: Vec::new(),
    };

    let tree_b = Tree {
        value: "b".to_owned(),
        children: Vec::new(),
    };

    let tree_c = Tree {
        value: "c".to_owned(),
        children: Vec::new(),
    };

    Tree {
        value: "abc".to_owned(),
        children: vec![tree_a, tree_b, tree_c],
    }
}

/*fn mapped_iter() -> Vec<String> {
    let tree = tree();
    let no_clone = NoClone;
    no_clone.descendants_iter(tree).map(|x| x.value).collect::<Vec<String>>()
}*/

fn mapped_vec() -> Vec<String> {
    let tree = tree();
    let no_clone = NoClone;
    no_clone.descendants_vec(tree)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|x| x.value)
        .collect::<Vec<String>>()
}
```

I would like to avoid the intermediate `collect`/`iter` and use `descendants_iter` which returns an `Iterator` (boxed until we get impl traits).

However, uncommenting the blocks calling this function causes the compiler to complain with the following error:

```
error: `no_clone` does not live long enough
  --> <anon>:63:1
   |
62 |     no_clone.descendants_iter(tree).map(|x| x.value).collect::<Vec<String>>()
   |     -------- borrow occurs here
63 | }
   | ^ `no_clone` dropped here while still borrowed
   |
   = note: values in a scope are dropped in the opposite order they are created

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Any ideas about how to use the `descendants_iter` function?

Comment: [Further minimized](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=76f606ad0a70a1d14965c552fcccd83c&version=stable).

Comment: [change the declaration](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=f3010554cfead7d64f39f13e5060c16d&version=stable) to `pub fn descendants_iter(self, from: Tree) -> Box<Iterator<Item = Tree>> {`?

Comment: @rampion that would consume `self`, which doesn't outwardly appear to be needed, especially considering that introducing a temporary (as shown in my comment) "solves" the problem.

Comment: @rampion that also fails to compile on the larger example in the question if I only change the signature of `descendants`